# Accessing UIButton from another class not working?

Tags: ios, class, variables, uibutton

I am trying to access my UIButton in my Play class from my CCLayerClass.

The problem is that it is not working!

Here is how I declare it in the Play class:
.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
```

.m

```
@synthesize pauseButton;
```

Then in the dealloc:

```
[pauseButton release];
```

Also of course I connect it then in Interface builder.

Then in my other class (My CCLayer) class. I try to do this:

```
Play *play = [[[Play alloc] init] autorelease];
[play.pauseButton setHidden:YES];
```

The thing is, is that it simply just does not hide the button. Is there any reason for this?

Thanks!

**Edit1**:
My Play.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
BOOL pauseButtonVisible;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
@property(readwrite) BOOL pauseButtonVisible;
```

.m

```
@synthesize pauseButton;

- (void)setPauseButtonVisible: (BOOL) variableToSet {
    pauseButtonVisible = variableToSet;
    if(pauseButton)
        [pauseButton setHidden: !pauseButtonVisible];
}
- (BOOL) pauseButtonVisible
{
    return(pauseButtonVisible);
}
```

viewWillAppear:

```
[pauseButton setHidden: !pauseButtonVisible];
```

I also made **sure I connected it in Interface Builder**

Then in CCLayerClass I do this:

```
Play *play = [[[Play alloc] init] autorelease];
    if(play.pauseButton == NULL) {  
        NSLog( @"pause button is NULL");
    }
```

But that NSLog gets called! Why is my pauseButton NULL? I just need to alloc it so it stays alive, is that possible?

Thanks!
        play.pauseButtonVisible = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  Hopefully third time is the charm (and after that, I'm giving up cause it's time for me to go to bed).

Here in the .h file, I'm keeping the new pauseButtonVisible BOOL property.

```
@interface Play : UIViewController
{
    BOOL pauseButtonVisible;
    IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
@property(readwrite) BOOL pauseButtonVisible;

@end
```

But in the .m file, we're doing something a little different:

```
@interface Play

// here we are rolling our own setters and getters
// instead of @synthesizing...
- (void)setPauseButtonVisible: (BOOL) variableToSet
{
    pauseButtonVisible = variableToSet;
    if(pauseButton)
        [pauseButton setHidden: !pauseButtonVisible];
}

- (BOOL) pauseButtonVisible
{
    return(pauseButtonVisible);
}

- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [pauseButton setHidden: !pauseButtonVisible];
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

and

```
Play *play = [[[Play alloc] init] autorelease]; // you should really be using initWithNibName, but anyways
play.pauseButtonVisible = YES;
```

So now, hopefully pause button will be visible or hidden at the appropriate time for while your code is running.

Comment: Play is a View Controller. Also I am not sure what you mean by having all the UI elements in Play loaded before pauseButton is not null. Does that mean I have to do something in code to fix that?

Comment: Also the pauseButton is in fact NULL so how would I fix that?

Comment: Instantiate it properly (via `[[Play alloc] initWithNibName: @"Play" bundle: NULL]` for example) then show it and **THEN** pauseButton will not be null and you can hide the button programatically. I hope my information helps you out!

Comment: What do you mean by show it? You mean show the view? I don't want to do that. I also am aiming to not call the ViewDidLoad of the Play view because that will mess up the way my app works. So pretty much I want to unhide Play's button without calling the ViewDidLoad of Play. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Add a BOOL variable to your Play object of "pauseButtonHidden".  After you alloc and init your Play view controller (which is still wrong, by the way), you can then `@synthesize pauseButtonHidden` and set that to TRUE. When `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` gets called (when it's time to truly load and show the Play view), you can do `[pauseButton setHidden: pauseButtonHidden]` in that method and all will be well.

Comment: Can you show this in code, I am a bit confused from reading it from a comment! Then ill accept and up vote your answer!

Comment: Actually I just tested it and it in fact doesn't work. I am doing it the opposite way, I hide the button at launch and I want to unhide it at a certain time in my CCLayerClass. What could be wrong? Edit: It seems that my pauseButton is still NULL.

Comment: I've changed my code yet again.  Now the variable is named pauseButtonVisible and another subtle change is the `!` sign in `[pauseButton setHidden: !pauseButtonVisible]`.  Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Nope still doesn't work. My NSLog shows that my pause Button is still in fact nil. Also keep in mind I want to make the pauseButton visible on NOT the launch of the Play View Controller. It is just at a random time in the app maybe thats why.

Comment: Hmm no luck, check my edit1! I am sure we are just one line away! :)

Comment: Maybe I should something like: play.pauseButton = UIButton alloc?